# Exclude video list by ID

Tags: youtube-data-api

I actually develop an application to watch Youtube together. Users add videos to create playlists that is stored on database. Thoses video is stored using their Youtube video ID.

Once added to the playlist, I want thoses videos to dissapear from API search result as there is no need to show them anymore.

Is there a parameter in the Youtube API that permit to exclude from search results a list of video by ID ?

Answer (score 0):

If what you describe boils down to uploading videos to YouTube (manually via the Web UI or programmatically using the API's [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint) and managing those videos by means of YouTube's Data API, then it suffices to set the [`privacyStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) of those videos to `unlisted`:

> [**`status.privacyStatus`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) (string)
> The video's privacy status.
>
> Valid values for this property are:
>
> - `private`
> - `public`
> - `unlisted`

Note that an `unlisted` video has a `privacyStatus` that is intermediary between `private` and `public` in the following sense:

- an `unlisted` video is not private, because users that know its ID can view it OK, using the player of YouTube's Web UI or an embedded player.
- an `unlisted` video is not public, since the YouTube's back-end will not return that video's ID as result of user search operations initiated through YouTube's Web UI or through YouTube's Data API.